# react native modal does not open

Tags: react-native

I am creating signup form and trying to sign in with phone number which returns verification code which i wanted to type in modal windrow. I wanted to open modal window after signup button has been click.I have sent visible property of modal to true but it is not being displayed on the screen. i have check the console value for the visibility property which is showing me "true" , which i could understand my modal will opn successfully but it is not doing anything. There is no errors also.

My code:

```
signIn = () => {

  const { name,  password, confirmPassword, mobile } = this.props;

  const object = { confirmPassword, password };
  const error = Validator('name', name)
    || Validator('password', password)
    || PasswordValidator(object)
    || Validator('mobile', mobile);

 const mobileNo = '+91'+mobile;

  if (error != null) {

    Alert.alert('Error', error);
  } else {
    console.log('else');
    const mobile = this.props.mobile;

    const userRef = firebase.database().ref(`/users/`);

    userRef.once('value', function(snapshot) {

      //If user is existed redirect to login page
      if(snapshot.val().mobile == mobile){
        Alert.alert('Error', 'Phone number is already registered! Please login with your credentials');
          NavigationService.navigate('Login');
      }

    });

  }     
    // If user is not exist signup
    firebase.auth().signInWithPhoneNumber(mobileNo)
      .then(confirmResult => this.setState({ confirmResult, message: 'Code has been sent!' },
      this.renderVerificationCodeInput()
    ))
      .catch(error => this.setState({ message: `Sign In With Phone Number Error: ${error.message}` }));
};


renderVerificationCodeInput() {

       console.log('code');
       const { codeInput } = this.state;
       this.setModalVisible(!this.state.modalVisible);
       console.log(this.state.modalVisible);

  <View style={{  position: 'absolute', top: 0, left: 0, right: 0, bottom: 0  }}>
  <Modal
    animationType="slide"
    transparent={false}
    visible={this.state.modalVisible}
    onRequestClose={() => {
      console.log('Modal has been closed');
    }}
  >
  {console.log(this.state.modalVisible)}
   <View >
    <Text>Enter verification code below:</Text>
     <Input
       autoFocus
      style={{ height: 40, marginTop: 15, marginBottom: 15 }}
       onChangeText={value => this.setState({ codeInput: value })}
       placeholder={'Code ... '}
       value={codeInput}
     />

     <Button title="Confirm Code" color="#841584" onPress={this.confirmCode} />
   </View>

  </Modal>

</View>
}
```

Comment: Could you please show all of your code, it seems that you are trying to set the state in a stateless component?

Comment: You are calling `this.setModalVisible` which does not update the state.  Did you want, `this.setState({modalVisible:true})`?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if its all the code,
if not you need to add state

```
state = {modalVisible: false}
```

and replace  `this.setModalVisible(!this.state.modalVisible);` 
to `this.setState({modalVisible:!this.state.modalVisible)`